# How to debug JAXB Marshaling failure due to identity contraint violations

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to write a tree of Java objects to XML using JAXB Marshaling. The marshal API call fails with the following error in the logs:

```
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; Duplicate unique value [ar-AE] declared for identity constraint of element "source-language".]
 at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:311)
```

I understand that there is some data in the objects that violates a unique value constraint. The Java objects have been generated from an XSD file which includes the said constraint.

I need some way to look at the data in the object tree and and identify the duplicate values so that they can be resolved at the data source.

Is there any easy way to get the Java objects data output to a string or a log file?

The Java objects have been generated from an XSD schema and do not include a sensible toString method that I could call on the root object of the tree and get a dump of all the data. I would need to write custom code to iterate over all the objects in the tree and print out the relevant fields.

Ideally I hope there would be some way in JAXB to temporarily ignore the constraint validation and just generate the XML for the object tree.

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple of ways to solve this

One way is to add toString methods. The toString methods are not generated by default to Java classes generated from XSD files. But they can be added using the JAXB basics plugins project. See this project - https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics

The other is simply to switch of XSD validation while marshaling. (should have thought of that first)

Using either way I was able to log the data and check what was causing the validation checks to fail manually.